Getting a Range error: Maximum call stack size exceeded, while multiplying 2 positive integers using recursion
#TODO: Create multiplication,multiply(), of two natural numbers using addition and our friend recursion..

def multiply(a, b):

    if b == 0:
        return 0
    if a==0:
        return 0
    if b==1:
        return a
    
    else:
        return a + multiply(a, b-1)

I believe the base case and the recursion function is correct. but the compiler says that there is a range error: Maximum call stack size exceeded. How do I limit the stack size?

Please show us how you call the function, use the [edit] button to add the code please.

This will inevitably fall into infinite recursion for b < 0. However, even if b is positive, its value determines the stack size. So, a large enough value will blow through the stack limit.

For something this simple, chatgpt is likely to give you a pretty good answer. I'd give that a try.

@darksky I wouldn't count on it: here is the result and it generated essentially the same code OP has with the same problem in it. When further prompting with the title it didn't fix the issue. Just slapped on increasing the stack limit and recommending iteration. Both of which are answers on this post already and both of which don't really address the problem directly, just ignoring it and doing a workaround. It also randomly decided to re-generate the recursion code and introduce an unneeded if b == 1: "Pretty good" it's not

A way to mitigate the limited recursion depth would be to divide b by 2 when it's even; that would push the recursion depth from b to O(log(b)), though you could say that partially goes against the "using only? addition" rule.

Some remarks on your code:

There is no guard against negative or non-integer arguments. If you would call the function with b negative or non-integer, it would lead to infinite recursion, leading to a Maximum call stack size exceeded error. Now, in your code there is a "TODO" comment that suggests that the arguments are natural numbers, so then this case would never happen.

There is no need to have a separate check for b==1, as this case will be dealt by the recursive call, when the next b will be 0.

The first two if statements can be combined into one.

There is no need for the else keyword. The only way execution can get at this point is when no return was executed, and so it would always be the "else" case. So unindent the final return statement and drop the line with else.


If the code challenge has been designed such that the available stack limit would be enough, then there is one more step you can take:

Swap the arguments when a is less than b. That way you guarantee that the smaller of the two determines the depth of recursion.

Code:
def multiply(a, b):  # guaranteed to be natural numbers
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return 0
    # Swap arguments if that leads to fewer recursive calls
    if a < b:
        a, b = b, a
    return a + multiply(a, b - 1)

It would not hurt to add code to deal with negative numbers and guard against non-integer numbers:
def multiply(a, b):
    # Don't accept floats
    if not isinstance(a, int) or not isinstance(b, int):
        raise ValueError("arguments for multiply function should be integers")
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return 0
    # Allow negative arguments: flip sign
    if a < 0:
        a, b = -a, -b
    if b < 0:
        return -multiply(a, -b)
    # Swap arguments if that leads to fewer recursive calls
    if a < b:
        a, b = b, a
    return a + multiply(a, b - 1)

NB: To increase the recursion depth that Python allows, see sys.setrecursionlimit, see also What is the maximum recursion depth, and how to increase it?.


Maximum call stack size exceeded

means that your function which calls itself was recursively calling itself beyond the supported/allowed call stack size.
Imagine the case when you call multiply(1, -1) in which case you flood your stack with function calls. Instead, try doing it iteratively, that is, not with a function that calls itself, but a loop that repeatedly adds a to the current result until the number of a values added equals b.

"Instead, try doing it iteratively" the task is to do it recursively. And I assume also to make people realise the limits of recursion and how to handle them.

Here's a variation that divides b by 2 when it's even, allowing to drastically reduce the recursion depth from b to O(log(b)) ; I've added the calls parameter to demonstrate the recursion depth (on top of that you can still add the protections implemented by @trincot). Oh, and value + value is there to stricly adhere to the rule "addition and recursion" :)
def multiply(a, b, calls=0):
    calls += 1
    if b == 0 or a == 0:
        return 0, calls

    if b % 2:
        value, calls = multiply(a, b - 1, calls)
        return a + value, calls
    else:
        value, calls = multiply(a, b//2, calls)
        return value + value, calls

Example:
multiply(2, 1000000)
(2000000, 27)

So 27 calls to the function when b = 1 000 000
